# heroku postgresql could not connect to server: Connection timed out

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to connect to postgres database in heroku using `heroku pg:psql postgresql-rigid-33416 --app murmuring-ocean-62645`, however I got this message

```
--> Connecting to postgresql-rigid-33416
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on host "ec2-50-17-225-140.compute-1.amazonaws.com" (50.17.225.140) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have tried to turn off my firewall but the problem persists. Any idea how to solve this?

EDIT:

```
heroku version
heroku/7.16.0 win32-x64 node-v10.10.0

heroku pg:info
=== DATABASE_URL
Plan:                  Hobby-dev
Status:                Available
Connections:           0/20
PG Version:            10.5
Created:               2018-10-09 14:03 UTC
Data Size:             7.6 MB
Tables:                0
Rows:                  0/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow:           Unsupported
Rollback:              Unsupported
Continuous Protection: Off
Add-on:                postgresql-rigid-33416
```

Comment: What's the output from `heroku version` and `heroku pg:info`?

Comment: @RangerRanger I added the output of those two commands.. Looking forward to your response..

Comment: I can telnet to that host/port. I'm doubtful that you've actually opened that host/port on your firewall. Make sure that's unblocked and I suspect that you'll be able to connect.

Comment: I used `netstat -a -n  | find "5432"` and it seems like it's working fine..
` TCP    0.0.0.0:5432           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    [::]:5432              [::]:0                 LISTENING`. Also, I tried to turn off my firewall, but still cannot connect to the database..

Comment: In addition to previous answer by @olucube.com besides Firewall settings, check out VPN connection. If you do not want to waste too much time on configuration for the correct access, just turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has this issue. I had same problem. I had to lower my network security by changing my Firewall Level on my local compter to 'Low' and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your firewall may still be preventing requests to that port - make sure to allow https requests out to port 5432.